# REG: Jmeter Test reporting framework

Tags: jmeter

I am trying build a report that gives comparison of response time between selected test runs. do we have any such extension or reporting framework which will take Test Run JtL files as input and generate comparison report of different response time ?

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion-
If you have a an output csv then create a dashboard report and jmeter response graph will give you comparison results

Use this command in cmd- i think you can also use jtl in this

```
jmeter -g C:\Users\output.csv -o C:\Users\Report
```

open an html file and check Response time graph.

and if don't have consolidated csv try consolidating manually and check graph of response time.

Answer (score 0):

1. The ready solution is [BM.Sense](https://sense.blazemeter.com/) results analysis platform
2. If you're trying to build your own "framework" and would like to copy paste the main logic from somewhere you can take a look at [Merge Results plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/)
3. You can put your test under [Jenkins](https://www.jenkins.io/)  orchestration and use [Performance Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/performance/) for building performance trends charts, the comparison logic is also there and the plugin is open source
4. You can use [Backend Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html) and store the execution results to an external source like [InfluxDB](https://www.influxdata.com/) and then visualize/compare them using [Grafana](https://grafana.com/)